# Twig token parser: How to parse tags with prefixes?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

My templates contain Twig “tags” that describe the pages. These are simple name/value pairs like

```twig
{% role "editor" %}
{% title "Foobar" %}
```

I can process them very nicely with a Twig extension and a custom token parser, like this:

```php
class RoleTokenParser extends \Twig_TokenParser
{
    public function parse(\Twig_Token $Token)
    {
        $TokenStream = $this->parser->getStream();
        $role = $TokenStream->expect(\Twig_Token::STRING_TYPE)->getValue();
        $TokenStream->expect(\Twig_Token::BLOCK_END_TYPE);
        return new RoleNode(['role' => $role], $Token->getLine(), $this->getTag());
    }

    public function getTag()
    {
        return 'role';
    }
}
```

But now I want to “prefix” the name parts like this:

```
{% myapp.role "editor" %}
```

I understand that the dot between `myapp` and `role` is a seperate token. What I don't get to work is to tell the `TokenParser` what to expect. I tried the following:

```php
// ...
$prefix = $TokenStream->expect(\Twig_Token::STRING_TYPE)->getValue();
$dot = $TokenStream->expect(\Twig_Token::PUNCTUATION_TYPE)->getValue();
$role = $TokenStream->expect(\Twig_Token::STRING_TYPE)->getValue();
// ...
```

… but that results in exceptions:

When my `Twig_TokenParser::getTag()` returns `myapp.role`, I get:

```
[Twig_Error_Syntax]
Unknown tag name "myapp". Did you mean "myapp.role" at line 3
```

When my `Twig_TokenParser::getTag()` returns only `myapp`, I get:

```
[Twig_Error_Syntax]                                                        
Unexpected token "punctuation" of value "." ("string" expected) at line 3
```

So, the question is: How do I tell the `Token_Parser` what tokens to expect, when the pattern is `{% myapp.role "editor" %}`?

(Btw, a solution that works on a similar syntax (like `{% myapp role "editor" %}`) would also be acceptable.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't have punctation in the tag name.

In your token parser, the STRING_TYPE you can refers to the first argument of the tag name, not the tag name itself.

Something like `{% role myapp "editor" %}` can be parsed using:

```
$prefix = $TokenStream->expect(\Twig_Token::NAME_TYPE)->getValue(); // myapp
$role = $TokenStream->expect(\Twig_Token::STRING_TYPE)->getValue(); // editor
```

Comment: That worked, thanks! I totally forgot I mustn't `expect` the tag name, as it's already removed from the token stream. However, based on your solution, I was even able to get it working with the dot (see below). ;)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to [Wouter J's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26843343/3908235):

It *is* possible to have a dot in the tag, but Twig won't consider the whole thing as a tag name, but instead start the token stream with the dot. But that's great, because this is exactly the desired behaviour.

You just have to start the parsing with the dot:

```
// works for {% myapp.key "value" %}
$dot = $TokenStream->expect(\Twig_Token::PUNCTUATION_TYPE, '.')->getValue();
$key = $TokenStream->expect(\Twig_Token::NAME_TYPE)->getValue();
$value = $TokenStream->expect(\Twig_Token::STRING_TYPE)->getValue();
```

The `getTag()` function has to return only `myapp` for this to work.